# Selecting User Name form User Table & Notes From Notes Table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to be able to select two tables at once..

I have a two tables named Notes and Users in Diary Database.

Basically what I want do is that I want to:

```
Select a particular column from Notes table Where Username = $somevariable from Users table.
```

Comment: take a look at `JOIN` clause.

Answer (score 0):

`select * from Notes n, Users u where n.foo=u.bar`

or

`select * from Notes n inner join Users u on n.foo=u.bar`

*foo* is a column in the Notes table, *bar* is a column in the Users table. * selects all columns from both tables, you can specify the desired column here instead of *

And please read for example this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp